# Why data frame not throwing RunTimeException with "FAILFAST" option in spark while reading using com.crealytics.spark.excel?

Tags: excel, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-excel

```
schema = <Schema of excel file>
df = spark.read.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel").\
 option("useHeader", "true").\  
 option("mode", "FAILFAST"). \
 schema(schema).\
 option("dataAddress", "Sheet1"). \
 load("C:\\Users\\ABC\\Downloads\\Input.xlsx")
 
 df.show()
```

Above pyspark read excel dataframe snippet is not failing/throwing runtime exception while reading (calling action using show() ) from incorrect/corrupt data. However option("mode", "FAILFAST") is working fine for CSV but when I am using com.crealytics.spark.excel jar I am facing issue i.e. its not failing code and giving results by substracting incorrect/corrupt data.

Does anyone encountered same issue ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Based on following documentation, no where mentioned **mode** is supported.

https://github.com/crealytics/spark-excel